# “EXC_BAD_ACCESS” while trying to animate a image with an NSArray and NSTimer

Tags: cocoa, animation, nstimer, nsimage, nsimageview

I am back again with my pigs (means cochon in French)! :)

I would like to created a at simple animated image with an NSTimer and I can't find example of it not with the iphone SDK.

after 3 second, the debugger displays : Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

here is the code, if you have some time to check it and say what you think of it..

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>


@interface maatView : NSView {
    NSArray *mesImagesCochon;
    NSImageView * monCochon;
    int counter;
}
-(void)tick;

@end
```

here is the .m file:

```
#import "maatView.h"


@implementation maatView

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code here.
            }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    counter=0;
    mesImagesCochon = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       [NSImage imageNamed:@"cochon.png"],
                       [NSImage imageNamed:@"cochon2.png"],
                       [NSImage imageNamed:@"cochon3.png"],
                       [NSImage imageNamed:@"cochon4.png"],
                       nil];

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3 
        target:self 
        selector:@selector(tick)
            userInfo:nil
            repeats:NO];

    monCochon = [[NSImageView alloc]init];
    [monCochon setFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)];

}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    // Drawing code here.
}

-(void)tick
{
    NSLog(@"method appele %d",mesImagesCochon.count);
    counter++;
    if (counter > mesImagesCochon.count) 
    {
        counter = 0;
    }

    [monCochon setImage:[mesImagesCochon objectAtIndex:counter]];
    [self addSubview:monCochon];
}
@end
```

Comment: OHHH i found it, it's because I forgot to add a -retain to the NSArray..

Comment: Retain? Don't we all use ARC now..?

Comment: If you switch to using ARC, you wouldn't need to retain the array. Without ARC, the other solution would be to use `[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:…]` to create the array.